# authz svn file parser in PHP

Tags: php, linux, svn

I'm creating web interface in PHP to manage svn repositories and svn users. I need to generate [dav_svn.authz](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2006/03/03/access-control-for-subversion-with-apache2-and-authz) file, where you can assign certain users and privileges to svn repository. Is there any existing PHP library which can do that for me or I have to write my own? My goal is not only to add new repository with its users, but also to modify any existing one.

Comment: Did you tried collabnet svn edge http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/ ?

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. Maybe some linux command line tool would be enough, so I can integrate it into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like standard .ini syntax, so you can probably use
[parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function.